# Ruby: Define own conversion method / protocol

Tags: ruby

I like to use Ruby's built in core conversions like

```
Integer("2")
Float("2.22")
Pathname("/etc/hosts")
```

But how can I define my own conversion method for a class? I have the following class

```
class Foobar
  def initialize
    # ... do some work
  end
end
```

and I want to have a method `Foobar("my value")` that converts the string `my value` into a class of `Foobar` (however you do it), or throws an `ArgumentError` if the input is not suitable.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: These "core conversions" are really methods named like appropriate classes and defined in `Kernel` module, for example: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how you define a method in Ruby? How you raise an exception? How you initialize an object from a string?

Comment: No, my question is not unclear. As you can read above, I'm asking how to define a conversion method / protocol for a specific class. I was unaware, that such methods are defined in Ruby's `Kernel` module, and not in the class itself. @sawa and @marek answered the question perfectly. Please read carefully before downvoting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
module Kernel
  def Foobar(string)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Added parentheses around formal parameters, as recommended by ruby style guide.

Comment: You should add `module_function :Foobar` to define it as a global function.